# Unable to render data elements of a FlatList react-native (Clojurescript)

Tags: react-native, clojurescript

I have the following:

```
(let [data [{:id "1" :name "foo" :address "address1" :time "some time"}
              {:id "2" :name "bar" :address "address2" :time "some time11"}
              {:id "3" :name "foo" :address "address3" :time "some time2"}
              {:id "4" :name "foo" :address "address4" :time "some time4"}]]
     [:> rn/FlatList {:data data
                      :renderItem
                      (fn [item]
                        (r/as-element
                         [:> rn/View
                          [:> rn/Text {:id (:id item)} 
                                      "Foo" (:id item)]]))

                      :key (random-uuid)}]
```

In this example, the Foo prints as an element of the flatlist, but not the id. Why is that?

[image]

Also, when I change the "key" key of flatlist to

```
:keyExtractor (fn [item]
                        (:id item))
```

I get the error:

```
Encountered two children with the same key null.
```

Why is (:id item) null in both cases?

-- EDIT --
I tried this for the renderItem key:

```
                     (fn [obj]
                         (let [item (.-item obj)]
                           (r/as-element
                            [:> rn/View 
                             [:> rn/Text {:id (:id item)}
                              "Foo"
                              (:address item)]])))
```

Still I only see the Foo.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the example of the RN FlatList it does not pass the actual item as the argument but instead something that has an item propety.

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
```

JS can be hard to deciper sometimes but this is destructuring `item` out of an object.

So in CLJS you need to use `(fn [obj] (let [item (.-item obj)] ...))` since we don't have destructuring for JS objects.

Comment: Didn't work. Still don't see the anything except Foo.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Thomas Heller's answer, it is important to remember that even after you have the `item`, it's *still* a JS object. That means you must use the get property (`.-`) to access the name and other values you defined.

```
(defn todo [meta-obj]
  (let [item (.-item meta-obj)]
    (r/as-element
     [:> rn/Text (.-name item)])))

(defn todo-list []
  [:> rn/FlatList {:data [{:id "1" :name "foo"}
                          {:id "2" :name "bar"}]
                   :render-item todo}])
```

It's certainly less ergonomic, so it might be worthwhile to look into libraries like [js-interop](https://github.com/applied-science/js-interop), which make object destructuring a bit easier.